# Split quad into 2 triangles

Tags: algorithm

I'm trying to implement an algorithm in C where I have an array consisting of 3 or 4 elements, each representing a vector (3D).

When I have 3 elements I draw only one triangle, with elements in the array (which are vectors) as its cornerpoints. When I have 4 elements in my array, it represents a quad. But since I can only draw triangles, I need to split the quad up into two triangles.

As the quad has 0, 1, 2, 3 as its cornerpoints, I split it up into two triangles with 0, 1, 2 and 2, 3, 0 as their cornerpoints. But now I seem to lose information sometimes, so I assume I cannot always divide a quad like this. Is there any kind of algorithm which solves this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure whether I understood the question correctly; under what circumstances would it be impossible to split a quad into 2 triangles? However, the orientation of the triangles might be important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quad can have at most one concave corner. If it has one, the splitting line has to be between this corner and the opposite one. So you first need to check if the quad has a concave corner.

Your problem could also be caused by self-intersecting quads.